# Do streaming http responses need to ping the browser to prevent the connection from being closed?

Tags: http, stream, api-design

I am implementing an API over HTTP that provides a slow streaming responses that may have lengthy gaps between chunks being sent. I'm trying to figure out if I should implement ping responses to prevent clients from timing out the request if it does not receive data for a lengthy amount of time. Since it is a streaming response I do not know if it's a requirement that I ping back with empty data periodically, or if the browser knows to keep the connection alive because it knows that it's a streaming response and not a standard response.

I've tried having a multi minute delay on chrome and it didn't timeout, but I'm not sure if there are other clients that may have timeouts I need to worry about.